# Issues with JSON.parse on input object form S3 - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Node newbie here I have a problem that I have been banging my head against for a few days now and I'm sure I am missing something small but my google too has failed me so far.

I have an AWS Firehose that is writing CloudWatch logs to S3 that are then picked up by a lambda function parsed and ingested into Elasticsearch. Or at least that is the plan. I reason I am using Firehose is that the data is coming from remote AWS accounts and sending all the logs to one place s3. I am able to pull the logs once in S3. Cloud watch logs by default are gzipped so the firehose is simply writing the files to S3 no transforming or anything. Now the issue :). Once I read the file from S3 I attempt to send it to a function transform to parse the data but it fails when trying to loop through the log which is JSON. I did a `console.log(payload)` and it appears to be in JSON format but running it through JSON.stringify the back to parsing does nothing. JSON.parse will work but the JSON will not be valid.
I am attaching the code below. I am not the original author someone in my company found it on GitHub. I just added the S3 parts to it. 
I added a file that was one of the logs as an example it's in a public s3 bucket if anyone wants to grab it. No worries its all test data nothing special.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/node-issue-stackoverflow/cwl-test-11-2018-08-26-00-45-34-84a4c3de-179a-4bf2-9376-895cdc063e6b+(1)

Pastebin [Link](https://pastebin.com/HBrhU1LS)

```
// v1.1.2
var https = require('https');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var endpoint = process.env.es_endpoint;
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params;

exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    // Get the event from S3 based on input
    params = {Bucket: input.Records[0].s3.bucket.name, Key: input.Records[0].s3.object.key};
    console.log(input.Records[0].s3);
    s3.getObject(params, function(error, event){
        if (error) { context.fail(error); return; }
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.Body);
        // decode input from base64
        var zippedInput = new Buffer(event.Body, 'base64');
        // decompress the input
        zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function(error, buffer) {
            if (error) { context.fail(error); return; }
            // console.log(buffer.toString());
            // parse the input from JSON
            var awslogsData = buffer.toString('utf8');

            // transform the input to Elasticsearch documents
            var elasticsearchBulkData = transform(awslogsData);

            // skip control messages
            if (!elasticsearchBulkData) {
                console.log('Received a control message');
                context.succeed('Control message handled successfully');
                return;
            }

            // post documents to the Amazon Elasticsearch Service
            post(elasticsearchBulkData, function(error, success, statusCode, failedItems) {
                console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify({
                    "statusCode": statusCode
                }));

                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));

                    if (failedItems && failedItems.length > 0) {
                        console.log("Failed Items: " +
                            JSON.stringify(failedItems, null, 2));
                    }

                    context.fail(JSON.stringify(error));
                } else {
                    console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
                    context.succeed('Success');
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

function transform(payload) {
    if (payload.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
        return null;
    }

    var bulkRequestBody = '';

    payload.logEvents.forEach(function(logEvent) {
        var timestamp = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp);

        // index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
        var indexName = [
            'cwl-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
        ].join('.');

        var source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields);
        source['@id'] = logEvent.id;
        source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString();
        source['@message'] = logEvent.message;
        source['@owner'] = payload.owner;
        source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup;
        source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream;

        var action = { "index": {} };
        action.index._index = indexName;
        action.index._type = payload.logGroup;
        action.index._id = logEvent.id;

        bulkRequestBody += [
            JSON.stringify(action),
            JSON.stringify(source),
        ].join('\n') + '\n';
    });
    return bulkRequestBody;
}

function buildSource(message, extractedFields) {
    if (extractedFields) {
        var source = {};

        for (var key in extractedFields) {
            if (extractedFields.hasOwnProperty(key) && extractedFields[key]) {
                var value = extractedFields[key];

                if (isNumeric(value)) {
                    source[key] = 1 * value;
                    continue;
                }

                jsonSubString = extractJson(value);
                if (jsonSubString !== null) {
                    source['$' + key] = JSON.parse(jsonSubString);
                }

                source[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return source;
    }

    jsonSubString = extractJson(message);
    if (jsonSubString !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(jsonSubString);
    }

    return {};
}

function extractJson(message) {
    var jsonStart = message.indexOf('{');
    if (jsonStart < 0) return null;
    var jsonSubString = message.substring(jsonStart);
    return isValidJson(jsonSubString) ? jsonSubString : null;
}

function isValidJson(message) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (e) { return false; }
    return true;
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function post(body, callback) {
    var requestParams = buildRequest(endpoint, body);

    var request = https.request(requestParams, function(response) {
        var responseBody = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            responseBody += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            var info = JSON.parse(responseBody);
            var failedItems;
            var success;

            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 299) {
                failedItems = info.items.filter(function(x) {
                    return x.index.status >= 300;
                });

                success = {
                    "attemptedItems": info.items.length,
                    "successfulItems": info.items.length - failedItems.length,
                    "failedItems": failedItems.length
                };
            }

            var error = response.statusCode !== 200 || info.errors === true ? {
                "statusCode": response.statusCode,
                "responseBody": responseBody
            } : null;

            callback(error, success, response.statusCode, failedItems);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        callback(e);
    });
    request.end(requestParams.body);
}

function buildRequest(endpoint, body) {
    var endpointParts = endpoint.match(/^([^\.]+)\.?([^\.]*)\.?([^\.]*)\.amazonaws\.com$/);
    var region = endpointParts[2];
    var service = endpointParts[3];
    var datetime = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, '');
    var date = datetime.substr(0, 8);
    var kDate = hmac('AWS4' + process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, date);
    var kRegion = hmac(kDate, region);
    var kService = hmac(kRegion, service);
    var kSigning = hmac(kService, 'aws4_request');

    var request = {
        host: endpoint,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/_bulk',
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Host': endpoint,
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
            'X-Amz-Security-Token': process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
            'X-Amz-Date': datetime
        }
    };

    var canonicalHeaders = Object.keys(request.headers)
        .sort(function(a, b) { return a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1; })
        .map(function(k) { return k.toLowerCase() + ':' + request.headers[k]; })
        .join('\n');

    var signedHeaders = Object.keys(request.headers)
        .map(function(k) { return k.toLowerCase(); })
        .sort()
        .join(';');

    var canonicalString = [
        request.method,
        request.path, '',
        canonicalHeaders, '',
        signedHeaders,
        hash(request.body, 'hex'),
    ].join('\n');

    var credentialString = [ date, region, service, 'aws4_request' ].join('/');

    var stringToSign = [
        'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        datetime,
        credentialString,
        hash(canonicalString, 'hex')
    ] .join('\n');

    request.headers.Authorization = [
        'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID + '/' + credentialString,
        'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders,
        'Signature=' + hmac(kSigning, stringToSign, 'hex')
    ].join(', ');

    return request;
}

function hmac(key, str, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(str, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}

function hash(str, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(str, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}
```

Comment: The S3 file you linked to appears to be 27 JSON strings concatenated together. I have not yet grokked all the code you posted, but I believe it is the case that you'll need to break the input up into to chunks of JSON and parse those separately to make things work.

Comment: Yeah I came to that conclusion last night as well but I have no clue how to break it up. It seems that is how the logs are being sent from cloud watch to firehouse to s3.